# Parsing text using Regex

Tags: java, regex

So I am trying to parse a String that contains two key components. One tells me the timing options, and the other is position.

Here is what the text looks like

```
KB_H9Oct4GFP_20130305_p00{iiii}t00000{ttt}z001c02.tif
```

The `{iiii}` is the position and the `{ttt}` is the timing options.

I need to separate the `{ttt}` and `{iiii}` out so I can get a full file name: example, position 1 and time slice 1 = KB_H9Oct4GFP_20130305_p0000001t000000001z001c02.tif

So far here is how I am parsing them:

```
    int startTimeSlice = 1;
    int startTile = 1;
    String regexTime = "([^{]*)\\{([t]+)\\}(.*)";
    Pattern patternTime = Pattern.compile(regexTime);       
    Matcher matcherTime = patternTime.matcher(filePattern);

    if (!matcherTime.find() || matcherTime.groupCount() != 3)
    {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorect filePattern: " + filePattern);
    }

    String timePrefix = matcherTime.group(1);
    int tCount = matcherTime.group(2).length();
    String timeSuffix = matcherTime.group(3);

    String timeMatcher = timePrefix + "%0" + tCount + "d" + timeSuffix;


    String timeFileName = String.format(timeMatcher, startTimeSlice);

    String regex = "([^{]*)\\{([i]+)\\}(.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);       
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(timeFileName);        



    if (!matcher.find() || matcher.groupCount() != 3)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorect filePattern: " + filePattern);
    }

    String prefix = matcher.group(1);
    int iCount = matcher.group(2).length();
    String suffix = matcher.group(3);

    String nameMatcher = prefix + "%0" + iCount + "d" + suffix;

    String fileName = String.format(nameMatcher, startTile);
```

Unfortunately my code is not working and it fails when checking if the second `matcher` finds anything in `timeFileName`.

After the first regex check it gets the following as the `timeFileName`: `000000001z001c02.tif`, so it is cutting off the beginning potions including the `{iiii}`

Unfortunately I cannot assuming which group goes first (`{iiii}` or `{ttt}`), so I am trying to devise a solution that just handles `{ttt}` first and then processes `{iiii}`.

Also, here is another example of valid text that I am also trying to parse: `F_{iii}_{ttt}.tif`

Comment: Do they all have the trailing 't' and 'z' characters to differentiate which is which should the order change? Your last example makes it look like the 't' and 'z' may be absent in some cases.

Comment: Indeed it is sadly not guaranteed that the z and t to be that as with the last example `F_{iii}_{ttt}.tif`

Comment: Is regex a requirement?

Comment: Can you guarantee the ordering when z and t are missing? If not, you'll definitely need some way of differentiating or you will get some incorrect results with the `F_{iii}_{ttt}.tif` files.

Comment: Regex is not required. I basically need to provide an easy tool for people to input text that indices how many digits are in the position and how many digits are in the time slices as well as which ones are position and time slice.

Comment: Also, do the files themselves have a date/time taken or a date/time modified in their metadata? If so, do they match the time parameter? That might be a better option than parsing a string for the timing portion. If they have GPS/position in their image metadata, you might not need to parse the file names at all.

Comment: One solution I was playing with, but cant figure out the regex is group all things up to '{t' and then count the number of t's and then group from '} .... And then for i it would be '{i'... etc. But I'm not sure how to do a search for a group like that

Comment: Can't you just use indexOf/substring to search for the '{' and '}'?

Comment: @Solace An example string is `KB_H9Oct4GFP_20130305_p0000001t000000001z001c02.tif`. There's no braces involved, OP used them to show where they are exactly.

Comment: After a bit of online testing I think I found a solution:

`(.*)\{t([t]+)\}(.*)` Gives me three groupings, and then I just need to add 1 to the tcount to account for the missing t that I found with `\{t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to follow:

- Find string {ttt...} in file name
- Form a number format based on no of "t" in string
- Find string {iiii...} in file name
- Form a number format based on no of "i" in string
- Use String.replace() method to replace time and possition

Here is the code:

```
String filePattern = "KB_H9Oct4GFP_20130305_p00{iiii}t00000{ttt}z001c02.tif";
int startTimeSlice = 1;
int startTile = 1;

Pattern patternTime = Pattern.compile("(\\{[t]*\\})");
Matcher matcherTime = patternTime.matcher(filePattern);

if (matcherTime.find()) {
    String timePattern = matcherTime.group(0);// {ttt}

    NumberFormat timingFormat = new DecimalFormat(timePattern.replaceAll("t", "0")
            .substring(1, timePattern.length() - 1));// 000

    Pattern patternPosition = Pattern.compile("(\\{[i]*\\})");
    Matcher matcherPosition = patternPosition.matcher(filePattern);

    if (matcherPosition.find()) {
        String positionPattern = matcherPosition.group(0);// {iiii}

        NumberFormat positionFormat = new DecimalFormat(positionPattern
                .replaceAll("i", "0").substring(1, positionPattern.length() - 1));// 0000

        System.out.println(filePattern.replace(timePattern,
                timingFormat.format(startTimeSlice)).replace(positionPattern,
                positionFormat.format(startTile)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first pattern looks like this:

```
String regexTime = "([^{]*)\\{([t]+)\\}(.*)";
```

This finds a string consisting of a sequence of zero or more non-`{` characters, followed by `{t...t}`, followed by other characters.

When your input is

```
KB_H9Oct4GFP_20130305_p00{iiii}t00000{ttt}z001c02.tif
```

the first substring that matches is

```
iiii}t00000{ttt}z001c02.tif
```

The `{` before the i's can't match, because you told it only to match non-`{` characters.  The result is that when you re-form the string to do the second match, it will start with `iiii}` and therefore won't match `{iiii}` like you're trying to do.

When you're looking for `{ttt...}`, I don't see any reason to exclude `{` or any other character from the first part of the string.  So changing the regex to

```
"^(.*)\\{(t+\\}(.*)$"
```

may be a simple way to fix this.  Note that if you want to make sure you include the entire beginning of the string and the entire end of the string in your groups, you should include `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string, respectively; otherwise the matcher engine may decide not to include everything.  In this case, it won't, but it's a good habit to get into anyway, because that makes things explicit and doesn't require anyone to know the difference between "greedy" and "reluctant" matching.  Or use `matches()` instead of `find()`, since `matches()` automatically tries to match the entire string.

Comment: Sorry I have a typo in the regex above. I will edit and remove the '. The ' was not in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a bit of testing I found a way to handle the case:

For parsing the `{ttt}` I can use the regex: `(.*)\\{t([t]+)\\}(.*)`

Now this means I have to increment tCount by one to account for the t I grab from `\\{t`

Same goes for `{iii}`: `(.*)\\{i([i]+)\\}(.*)`

Comment: Why increment by one?  Just move the left parenthesis: `(t[t]+)`, and now it will catch all the `t`'s in the group.  Or `(t{2,})` matches two or more `t`'s.  By the way, there's no reason to put a single character in square brackets, unless you think it's more readable.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Here is a more final version that includes everything. `(.*)(\\{[i]+\\})(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way to do this (as confirmed by http://regex101.com/r/vG7kY7) is

```
(\{i+\}).*(\{t+\})
```

You don't need the `[]` around a single character you are matching. Keep it simple. `i+` means "one or more `i`'s", and as long as these are in the order given, this expression will work (with the first match being `{iiii}` and the second `{ttttt}`).

You may need to escape the backslash when writing it in a string...